# Ionic v1 - iPhone X notch covers content in landscape orientation

Tags: ionic-framework

I am using the suggested `viewport-fit=cover` segment in my meta tag, in my Ionic v1 app. That works fine in the vertical view, however, when I turn the phone and it enters landscape mode, no padding is applied to the content, and some of the screen is not shown because of the iPhone X's notch.

How do I get it fixed so that content is not covered neither in portrait nor landscape more?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, ensure that the following meta tag has been added:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1,user-scalable=no, width=device-width, height=device-height, viewport-fit=cover">
```

Then you would want to following the docs for the [Status Bar cordova plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/status-bar). You'll see on that page that they use `this.statusBar.overlaysWebView(true);` I think you would need that so that the notch (including the rest of the status bar) overlays the webview that everything is loaded into.

Comment: I don't know if that would work. The status bar remains at the top of the screen, even in landscape mode, so it's not the status bar that's the problem. It's the actual screen content, or the side menu, that gets covered by the notch.